# How to show spree product variant images only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Right now I've the following piece of code, which retrieves all images attached to Spree products.

```
<% @product.images_by_variant.each do |variant_id,images| %>
    <ul class="gallery gallery-<%= variant_id %>" data-variant="<%= variant_id %>">
        <% images.each do |image| %>
            <li>
                <%= image_tag(image.attachment.url(:single)) %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

However, there are also images displayed that represent all variants. I want to hide those.

How can I only show variant (different colors for example) for products?

Cheers!

Comment: Which version of Spree are you using? I don't see `images_by_variant` defined on `Spree::Product` in 2.4 or master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the **products_controller_decorator.rb**, I added the following piece of code to the **show** method:

```
variants = @product.variants
if variants.blank?
    @variants = @product
elsif variants.length > 1
   @variants = variants.reject {|variant| variant.is_master? }
end
```

In the **view** I rendered the following partial:

```
<% if @variants == @product %>
    <%= render partial: 'product_single/product_gallery', locals: {variant: @product} %>
<% else %>
    <% @variants.each do |variant| %>
        <%= render partial: 'product_single/product_gallery', locals: {variant: variant} %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```